# How to add script type="module" in django admin

Tags: python, django, es6-modules

If I want some javascript functionality in my Django admin, I usually go about it using the `Media` class like this:

```
@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    class Media:
        js = ('js/my_script.js',)
```

But I now have a script that is a ES6 module so I would like Django to render it like:

```
<script src="path/to/static/js/my_script" type="module"></script>
```

and using the `Media` class doesn't render the `type="module"` attribute.

Any help or tips to achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your custom change_form.html template, extend the admin_change_form_document_ready block and add the event listener code

```
{% extends 'admin/change_form.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block admin_change_form_document_ready %}
{{ block.super }}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'app/your_file.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I was hoping to use something similar to the Media class but the other answer clears this up. Looks like this answer is the most appropriate way at the moment. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to use `Media` class for this, if you check at the [code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/widgets.py#L80), the method will always render the same `type="text/javascript"`.

If you really want to go with the `Media` way, you could create your own `Media`class and inherit from `forms.Media`, then you could try using `Media` [as a dynamic property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/media/#media-as-a-dynamic-property) that would be able to generate a script with `type="module"`.

Another option is to use a custom template as suggested before, or even considering adding a [templatetag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags) to your app in order to add ES6 modules in your template.

Comment: Thanks, this answer aids in completeness and makes it clear that the other answer is arguably the best answer for the moment as we cannot immediately use the Media class

Comment: You can't implement it by `inherit` way, because there is a lot of hardcoded Media usage in django/contrib/admin/options.py. You can only overwrite it like my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75636263/2134775

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Django version 4.1, it is possible to define the complete `<script …></script>` tag as HTML rather than just specifying the path to the given file.

Your ModelAdmin class then can be rewritten as:

```
from django.utils.html import format_html
from django.templatetags.static import static

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    class Media:
        js = [format_html(
            '<script type="module" src="{}"></script>', 
            static('js/my_script.js')
        )]
```

Comment: Works like a charm! It should be the accepted answer nowadays :)

Answer (score 0):

We can overwrite the `Media.render_js` to add anything we want to add to  tag.

```
from django.forms.widgets import Media

def render_js(self) -> List[str]:
    script_js = []

    for path in self._js:
        module_mark = ""

        # Put your own condition here, in my case it generates
        # <script type="module" src="http://localhost:5173/@vite/client"></script>
        # and <script type="module" src="http://localhost:5173/src/custom_admin.ts"></script>
        # into head scripts
        if isinstance(path, str) and (
            "custom_admin" in path or "@vite/client" in path
        ):
            module_mark = ' type="module"'

        js = format_html(
            '<script%s src="{}"></script>' % module_mark,
            self.absolute_path(path),
        )

        script_js.append(js)

    return script_js


Media.render_js = render_js

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        js = (
            "http://localhost:5173/@vite/client",
            "http://localhost:5173/src/custom_admin.ts",
        )
```

Just adjust above code to adapt your logic and add it to your admin.py.

Answer (score -1):

```
@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    class Media:
        module = ('js/my_script.js',)
```

You can just change js to replace module its define is type of src

It‘s working for me.

Comment: I fail to see how this can work without modification or custom logic to process Media, the internals of Django do not support module =, there's no way to output this.